# binding data from database to two column of gridview programmatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me out, I am new to asp.net.  my gridview have 5 columns and I want to bind two columns of this gridview to  select data from database while user enter data through the other columns of the gridview in order to save the gridview data to another table. But I have problem with binding data to 2 columns out of 5 columns of the gridview. How can I achieve this.  Here is my code

```
string classid = query.Class + query.Class_division;
var q = (from cl in db.StudentTbs where        cl.Admission_class == classid select new {
id=cl.UnquieStudentId, Name= cl.Surname+", "+ cl.FirstName +" "+ cl.OtherName
}).ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
if(q.Count>0)
{
    DataRow row = null;
    dt.Columns.Add("Series No");
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    foreach( var row2 in q)
    {
        row = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(row2.id);
        dt.Rows.Add(row2.Name);
    }
     GridView1.DataSourceID = null;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

[Image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2a3d.png)

Comment: Pls dont include text images.

Answer (score 1):

Format your GridView1 in your as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Series No" DataField="Series No" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="name" />
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```